# Можно ли "бросать воду"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли написать "бросать воду на каменку", или обязательно нужно "лить воду на каменку"?

Answer (score 2):

Вполе можно. Тот, кто хоть раз видел, как это делают знатоки, поймет, почему они предпочитают именно "бросать" - коротким, резким движением. Начнешь лить - "придушишь" жар. 
Что касается "поддать", то "поддают пару". Именно таким образом - бросая воду на каменку.

Answer (score 2):

1) **Лить воду** — это неточное выражение, воду на каменку **плескают** , например:  "Войдя, следует открыть дверь, плеснуть на каменку полный ковш воды".

**ПЛЕСКАТЬ**, 4. кого-что или чем. Зачерпнув жидкости, брызгать ею, выливать её на кого-, что-л. П. водой в лицо. П. рукой из тазика. П. воду пригоршнями. С шумом п. воду на тело. **П. воду на раскалённые камни парилки.**

2) **Но и слово "плеснуть" не совсем точно выражает производимое действие,** поэтому специалисты используют выражение **"бросить воду на каменку."** Вот как это объясняется.

**Учитель:** Почему нужно подбрасывать воду маленькими порциями, а не выливать на каменку сразу большую порцию?

**Ответ:** Когда **небольшие порции воды с силой бросают на каменку**, она
разбрызгивается маленькими капельками. Попадая на камни, горячие капельки мгновенно испаряются, превращаясь в пар, температура которого сравнима с температурой каменки. Раскаленный пар вызывает повышение общей температуры парной. [Урок по физике в 10 классе по теме "Физика в бане" | infourok.ru](https://infourok.ru/urok-po-fizike-v-klasse-po-teme-fizika-v-bane-307260.html)

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял, имеется в виду верхняя часть печи в бане, на которую **льют** воду для образования пара (МАС).

Как видно из словарной статьи, на каменку воду **льют**. Тем не менее можно воду и *бросать* (резким движением, взмахом заставлять перемещаться в воздухе в каком-л. направлении), соответствующие примеры [встречаются](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%E1%F0%EE%F1%E0%F2%FC&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%E2%EE%E4%E0&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=) в Корпусе.

Интересно, что можно еще *поддавать* водой: "Из бани то и дело вместе с клубами пара вырывалось шипенье, — это парильщики поддавали на раскаленную каменку водой" (Шишков, "Гордая фамилия").